# Swift unwrap multiple optionals depending on each other in one if statement

Tags: swift, option-type

I know that you can unwrap multiple optionals in one line with the if let syntax like so

```
if let x = optionalX, y = optionalY {
    //do something
}
```

What I want is unwrap multiple optionals that depend on each other in one line. Currently it looks like this

```
if let a = optionalA {
    if let ab = a.optionalB {
        if let abc = ab.optionalC {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

IMO this looks really unclean, especially if you also want else cases because you have to add it to every case. What I want would look something like this but it does not work

```
if let a = optionalA, ab = a.optionalB {
    //do something
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above code does work!

I had an error somewhere else which made it look like the error occured in the statement.

Comment: You can do that. If you have some error - provide it to us; should be no errors.

Comment: http://iswift.org/playground?7FhqiB

Comment: You forgot the `var` in `optionalB : B?` in your test code. Otherwise it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: You better use [IBM swift playground](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl), it will show you this error.

Comment: http://iswift.org/playground?hWHhnR
I forgot the var and somehow I did not see that in xCode when I tried it there with more complex code and online. Sorry for stupidness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wish to work with the (possible) instance inner variable `b` (type `B`) of `a` (type `A`), you could use optional chaining in a single optional binding clause

```
class A {
    var optionalB : B?
}

class B {}

var optionalA : A?

// in case you needn't actually use optionalA, but only its
// possibly non-nil instance member `optionalB`
if let b = optionalA?.optionalB {
    //do something with b
}
```

Comment: I like this answer the most because it is a nice alternative. Should be noted that the syntax in the questions works as well.

Comment: The syntax you used in your question works up to Swift 2.2. Swift 3.0 requires adding `let` to specify that it's an optional unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the class declaration, not with the optional.

`classA` should look more like:

```
classA {
  let optionalB : B? = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to [mix conditions and optional unwrapping separated by commas in a single if condition in Swift 3.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md) (and maybe 2.3). In order for the compiler to be able to differentiate an optional unwrapping, you need to write `let` again after each comma :

```
if let a = optionalA,
   let ab = a.optionalB {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
guard let a = optionalA,
      let b = a.optionalB,
      let c = b.optionalC 
else {
  // else implementation
 return
}

// do something with constants a, b and c
```